# how do I use sql DISTINCT,UNION with where clause

Tags: sql, where-clause, union, distinct, dbf

Dear All,

how do I use sql DISTINCT,UNION with where clause?

column "GDN" is in the database table "GPG".

please recommend and solution.

Thanks

TABEL : GPD

| PNM |
| --- |
| GPPI12301001 |
| GPPI12301002 |
| GPPI82301001 |
| GPPI82301002 |

TABEL : GPG

| GDN | PNM |
| --- | --- |
| A.04.01.002.001 | GPPI12301001 |
| A.04.01.002.001 | GPPI12301002 |
| A.04.01.008.001 | GPPI82301001 |
| A.04.01.008.001 | GPPI82301002 |

desired result

| PNM |
| --- |
| GPPI12301001 |
| GPPI12301002 |

```
 Dim query As String = "SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM GPD UNION SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM GPG ORDER BY PNM"
```

Below where clause I mean in the GPG database table

```
WHERE GDN = 'A.04.01.002.001'
```

Comment: UNION would only add unique values to the result set

Comment: What are you getting? What are you trying to achieve? Please post a sample table to query against as well as an example of your desired output.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` combined with `UNION` makes no sense.

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless , I have updated the sample and the results in the desired

Comment: @jarlh , `Dim query As String = "SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM GPD UNION SELECT DISTINCT PNM FROM GPG ORDER BY PNM"` this sql is already appropriate in combobox but I don't know how to add where clause

Comment: Since all you sample GPG data have the same 'A.04.01.002.001' GDN value, it's hard to understand the WHERE clause you have...

Comment: @jarlh , but in the column "PNM" in the GPG table it is different

Comment: Add some more sample data, with values not expected to be returned. The current data is too trivial to show the actual problem.

Comment: why is there a UNION here at all if you only want the two PNM values that match the given GDN value in the second table?

Answer (score 0):

Each `SELECT` has its own `WHERE` clause. And the `UNION` has an `ORDER BY` for its final result.

```
SELECT PNM
FROM GPD

UNION

SELECT PNM
FROM GPG
WHERE GDN = 'A.04.01.002.001'  -- belongs to the UNIONS's 2:nd SELECT

ORDER BY PNM  -- belongs to the whole UNION
```

Comment: your answers still appear all in the "PNM" column

Comment: Yes,. and your desired result has a column named PNM.

Comment: I think you need to revisit your initial question @Malf. Here is a dbfiddle built using the sample data you provided. Perhaps you are unaware that you have 4 unique PNM values in those two tables.  [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/040CNQO1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT PNMs.PNM 
FROM (
        SELECT PNM FROM GPD
    UNION
        SELECT PNM
        FROM GPG
        WHERE GDN = 'A.04.01.002.001'
) PNMs
ORDER BY PNM
```

Comment: UNION by definition returns only the DISTINCT values

Answer (score 0):

You will never get your desired output so long as you UNION all the PNM values from the GPD table.  You will always get all the PNM values instead of the subset related to the given GDN value.

All you need is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PNM
FROM GPG
WHERE GDN = 'A.04.01.002.001'
ORDER BY PNM
```